Diagonal entries of the inverse of ATA under specific conditions
Consider the matrix $ A^T A $, the product of the transpose of $ A $ with $ A $. Let $ A^T A $ be invertible. It is also known that all columns of $ A $ have zero sample covariance with other columns. Note that sample covariance is defined as $ \text{Cov}(a_i, a_j) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{i,k} - \bar{a}_i)(a_{j,k} - \bar{a}_j) $, where $ \bar{a}_i $ is the mean of the $ i $-th column of $ A $.
In particular, this does not mean that the columns of $ A $ are orthogonal.
Now consider the inverse of $ A^T A $. How can we derive a formula for the diagonal entries of $ (A^T A)^{-1} $ analytically?
Computationally, it seems to be given by
$$
\frac{1}{\sum (a_i - \bar{a})^2}.
$$
